# Why does my form in Django save successfully except for one field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

my form in forms.py is then passed to this method in my views.py, if I go into python shell and print objects from MyProfile, all of the fields show values except for nearbyzips, which shows None.  As you can see below, I am trying to manually assign a value to nearbyzips when the form is saved.

inside views.py

```
@secure_required
@login_required
def profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form=EditProfileForm,
                 template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
                 extra_context=None, **kwargs):
profile = get_profile(user)
form = edit_profile_form(instance=profile, initial=user_initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid()
            cleanzipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']

            nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code=cleanzipcode).location)
            zip_codes = list(nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))
            //print zip_codes
            form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] = zip_codes
            //print form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips']

            profile=form.save()

            return redirect(redirect_to)
```

models.py

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    streetaddress=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                       max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    phone=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=16)
    websiteurl=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=38)
```

Something to keep in mind, if I go into python shell and run:

```
nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='97202').location
print nearestzips
```

It prints all the Postal Codes I would expect.  So I'm not sure where exactly is broken.  I don't see any errors in my logs.

UPDATE:
I have added print statements in my views.  printing zip_codes and form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] both show:

```
[u'97202', u'97206', u'97214', u'97215', u'97239']
```

But it still does not appear to be saving to the form.

Comment: Since you never call form.save at all, I can't imagine how any of the fields could be saved.

Comment: sorry that was actually included I must not have pasted it.

Comment: Can we see your model?

Comment: And what is nearbyzips? What field type is it? You are passing a list, which seems strange.

Comment: Oh, its an IntegerField, is that why maybe?

Comment: i'm also confused why the log shows no errors for this.  Shouldn't failing to pass a value to a form field produce an error?

Comment: @GlynJackson, I added the model

Comment: In this line: PostalCode.objects.get(code='cleanzipcode')... you probably don't want the quotes around cleanzipcode.  You should print the value cleanzipcode after you assign it

Comment: this might be a dumb question but will it print to my log if i include a print statement?

Comment: It will print to the terminal that is running your server (at least if that is the built in django server)

Comment: okay that has helped a lot, see my updated post.

Comment: Is the issue that I cannot save a list to a IntegerField?  I'm not sure what else it could be...

Comment: From your models nearby zips is a ``Integer Field`` this could only store an integer value and not a list of integers! You should be getting an error when saving to this if passing a list. You said its not saving, are you sure it is not  just failing silently?

Answer (score 0):

2 things stand out to me here.

Your form is created for some kind of profile model (get_profile_model()) -- does this profile model have a field called `nearbyzips`?

If your model does have a field called `nearbyzips`, explicitly include it (and all the fields you want to update) in a [tuple/list of `fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/) in your form class's inner `Meta` class.

Also, I don't see you calling the `save` method on your form class in your view function (i.e. `form.save()`).

Comment: It is from a model, yes there is a nearbyzips field.  If I fill out and save the form and go into python shell and print that object, I see all the fields including nearbyzips, however nearbyzips = None

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 tzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='cleanzipcode').location)
```

to this:

```
tzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code=cleanzipcode).location)
```

Comment: i fixed that it was a typo, but i have updated my OP because it's still not working.