# Can I pass a list to a IntegerField?

Tags: django, django-queryset

When a user edits their profile and submits the form, this function takes the user's submitted postal code, and finds the 5 closest postal codes and puts them into a list.  This part is confirmed to be working.  What I'm trying to do after that, is save that list to a model field (in the same MyProfile model) called nearbyzips.  For whatever reason, the list of postal codes is NOT saving to the model instance.

print form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] gives me this:

```
[u'97202', u'97206', u'97214', u'97215', u'97239']
```

What I am trying to eventually do, is create a filter where the currently logged in user can browse items for sale by the surrounding zipcodes.  Here is the query for that:

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=user.nearbyzips)
```

I'm not sure why the list of postal codes is not saving to the nearbyzips field.  My first and main question is, can I even save a list of integers to an IntegerField?  When I submit the form, and then check the values for each field, all the correct values show up for each field except 'nearbyzips' which returns None. Is that my problem is that I'm using the wrong field.  The query above is filtering a list of values, so then going back a step, is it not possible to save a list of values to a single model field?  From reading other posts I know I coul serialize the list into JSON first and then save that to the model, but I would like to know if that is required for what I'm trying to do.

EDIT:

Here is a bigger snippet of the actual function inside views.py:

```
if form.is_valid()
            cleanzipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']

            nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code=cleanzipcode).location)
            zip_codes = list(nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))
            form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips'] = zip_codes

            //print form.cleaned_data['nearbyzips']

            profile=form.save()
```

Comment: The Integer field isn't made to hold an array of data. Consider using a foreign-key relationship so that you can query like: ```Entries.objects.filter(id=someId).zipcode_set```.... etc. See the field type [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#integerfield). Another option is creating your own field type, using generic foreign keys, or using a DB specific django app to accomplish this behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my form in Django save succesfuly except for one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549474/why-does-my-form-in-django-save-succesfuly-except-for-one-field)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No, you cannot pass a list to an integerfield.

Depending on how long it takes you to calculate your 5 nearest zip codes, it may be easier to create a property on your model that calculates and returns the 5 nearest codes using your current method.

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
@property
def nearest_zips(self):
    return CalculateNearestZip(self.zip)
```

Comment: Can I pass a list of integers to a Charfield?